# How to do Callbacks with Dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic, callback

I keep getting this error and not sure how to correct it

> Error 1   Cannot use 'Callback' as an argument to a dynamically
>    dispatched operation because it is a method group. Did you intend to
>    invoke the method?

```
    //...
    if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {              
        client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
        LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
        try
        {

            dynamic meResult = operationResult.Result;

            var openId = meResult.id;
            var email = meResult.emails.preferred;
            //MessageBox.Show(openId);
            //MessageBox.Show(email);
           userService.SignIn(openId, email, Callback);


        }
        catch (LiveConnectException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error calling API: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void Callback(ErrorModel error)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.FriendlyErrorMsg, error.Caption, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

public void SignIn(string id, string email, Action<ErrorModel> callBack)
{

}
```

Comment: What's the signature of `userService.SignIn`?

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that this call is dynamic:

```
userService.SignIn(openId, email, Callback);
```

It has to be, because `openId` and `email` are inferred to be of type `dynamic`:

```
var openId = meResult.id;
var email = meResult.emails.preferred;
```

You can't use a method group conversion like this in a dynamic call - it's just one of the restrictions of using `dynamic`.

So, options:

- Give `openId` and `email` explicit types, which (if `userService` isn't `dynamic`) will make the call non-dynamic, at which the method group conversion will work. This just means specifying the types explicitly, as there's an implicit conversion available from `dynamic`:

  ```
  string openId = meResult.id;
  string email = meResult.emails.preferred;
  userService.SignIn(openId, email, Callback);
  ```
- Create a *specific* delegate type instance from the `Callback` method, if you want to keep the `SignIn` call dynamic:

  ```
  var openId = meResult.id;
  var email = meResult.emails.preferred;
  // Or use whichever delegate type is actually appropriate for SignIn
  userService.SignIn(openId, email, new Action<ErrorModel>(Callback));
  ```